# Vue.js How to clear the selected option in a dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I added a button inside my dropdown that needs to clear the selected city.
I added an event but it isn't clearing the selected option.
Could you please suggest me what am I doing wrong ? Thank you very much.

This is the button in my dropdown

[image]

```js
methods: {
        ...mapActions({
            fetchCitiesByName: "fetchCitiesByName",
            fetchCityDetails: "fetchCityDetails",
        }),
        async onClientComboSelect({value, label})
        { 
            this.cityId = value;
            this.city = label;
            this.option.city = label;
            this.additionalSearchField = {cityId: this.option.cityId, label: this.option.city};
            await this.fetchCityInfo({id: this.option.cityId, label: this.option.city});
        },
        noCitySelected()
        {
            this.option.cityId = null;
            this.$emit('input', this.option.cityId);
            this.$emit('on-button-action', item);
        },
```

```html
<!--  Select City -->
          <div
            class="select-form-field"
          >
            <label
              for="city"
              class="inline-3-columns"
            >
              <span class="title__field">City*</span>
              <combo-select
                id="city"
                v-model="option.cityId"
                api-location="fetchCitiesByName"
                api-details-location="fetchCityDetails"
                search-parameter="cityName"
                :additional-search-fields="additionalSearchField"
                :transformer="cityTransformer" 
                :button="{event: noCitySelected, text: 'No City', icon: 'minus'}"      
                :config="{
                  ...comboConfig,
                  searchLabel: 'Search Cities',
               
                }"
                :button-event="noCitySelected"
                class="input input__typeahead"
                @on-select-item="onCityComboSelect"
              />
              <input
                v-model="option.cityId"
                type="hidden"
                name="cityId"
              >
            </label>
          </div>
          <!--  End -->
```

here is the dropdown combo-select that I need I need to use. Is it possible to clear

```js
<script>

const COMBO_STATES = Object.freeze({
    OPEN: "OPEN",
    CLOSED: "CLOSED"
});

const LOADING_STATES = Object.freeze({
    LOADING: "LOADING",
    BLOCKED: "BLOCKED",
    DEFAULT: "DEFAULT"
});

export default {
    directives: {
        clickOutside: vClickOutside.directive,
        focus: {
            inserted: (el) =>
            {
                el.focus();
            }
        }
    },
    components:
    {
        InfiniteScroll
    },
    model: {
        prop: 'selectedId',
    },
    props:
    {
        apiLocation: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            default: ""
        },
        apiDetailsLocation: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
            default: ""
        },
        transformer: {
            type: Function,
            required: true,
            default: () => ([])
        },
        selectedId: {
            type: Number|null,
            required: false,
            default: null
        },
        selectedItems: {
            type: Array,
            required: false,
            default: () => ([])
        },
        searchParameter: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
            default: "name"
        },
        // temporary as the form css is too much hassle to adjust
        details: {
            type: String|null,
            required: false,
            default: null
        },
        additionalSearchFields: {
            type: Object,
            required: false,
            default: () => ({})
        },
        getter: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
            default: ""
        },
        button: {
            type: Object,
            required: false,
            default: null
        },
        config: {
            type: Object,
            required: true,
            default: () => ({})
        },
        canSendDifferentValue: {
            type: Boolean,
            required: false,
            default: true
        }
    },
    data()
    {
        return {
            searchable: "",
            openState: COMBO_STATES.CLOSED,
            itemsInitializationNotEmpty: false,
            selectedItem: CSItem(),
            items: [],
            iterations: 0,
            isLoading: false,
            page: 0,
            pagingLoadingState: LOADING_STATES.DEFAULT,
            defaultConfig: {
                itemsPerPage: 20,
                numberOfItemsShown: 4,
                searchLabel: "Search for more...",
                showDefaultLabelOnSelect: false,
                clearSelectedItems: false,
                isEditable: true,
                isImmediate: true
            }
        };
    },
    computed:
    {
        hasSubitemSlot()
        {
            return !!this.$slots.subitem || !!this.$scopedSlots.subitem;
        },
        isComboSelectEditable()
        {
            return this.innerConfig.isEditable;
        },
        isOpen()
        {
            return this.openState === COMBO_STATES.OPEN;
        },
        comboItems()
        {
            let items = this.items;
            if(this.innerConfig.clearSelectedItems)
                items = this.items.filter(({id}) => !this.selectedItems.includes(id));

            return CSItemList(items, this.transformer);
        },
        comboSelectItem()
        {
            const defaultLabel = this.innerConfig.isEditable ? "Select" : "";
            if(this.innerConfig.showDefaultLabelOnSelect) return defaultLabel;
            if(this.selectedItem.value)
            {
                const {label = defaultLabel} = this.comboItems.find(({value}) => value === this.selectedItem.value) || {};
                return label;
            }
            return this.selectedItem.label ? this.selectedItem.label : defaultLabel;
        },
        innerConfig()
        {
            return Object.assign({}, this.defaultConfig, this.config);
        },
        hasNoItems()
        {
            return this.filterItems(this.items).length === 0;
        },
        skip()
        {
            return this.innerConfig.itemsPerPage * this.page;
        },
        isPagingLoading()
        {
            return this.pagingLoadingState === LOADING_STATES.LOADING;
        },
        isPagingLoadingBlocked()
        {
            return this.pagingLoadingState === LOADING_STATES.BLOCKED;
        }
    },
    watch:
    {
        additionalSearchFields:
        {
            deep: true,
            handler(newValue, oldValue)
            {
                if(newValue && !isEqual(newValue, oldValue))
                    this.getItems(false);
            }
        },
        selectedId: function(newValue, oldValue)
        {
            if(newValue === oldValue) return;
            this.findSelectedItem();
        },
        items: function(newValue, oldValue)
        {
            const allItems = this.filterItems(newValue);
            if (allItems.length === 0 && oldValue.length !== 0) return;
            if (allItems.length === 0 && oldValue.length === 0 && this.itemsInitializationNotEmpty) return;
            if(allItems.length === 0)
                this.$emit("on-no-items");
            this.itemsInitializationNotEmpty = true;
        }
    },
    async mounted()
    {
        try
        {
            if(!this.innerConfig.isImmediate) return;

            const initialSearchParams = this.searchable.length > 0 ? {[this.searchParameter]: this.searchable} : {};
            this.items = await this.$store.dispatch(this.apiLocation, Object.assign({
                top: this.innerConfig.itemsPerPage,
                load: false,
                skip: this.page,
                ...initialSearchParams
            }, this.additionalSearchFields
            ));

            this.findSelectedItem();

            this.searchValue$ = "";
            this.requestSubscription = requestSourceService
                .getInstance()
                .search
                .subscribe(search =>
                {
                    const {source, value} = search;
                    if(this.searchValue$ === value)
                        Reflect.apply(source.cancel, null, [
                            "Cancel previous request"
                        ]);

                    this.searchValue$ = value;
                });
        }
        catch(error)
        {
            this.errorHandler();
        }
    },
    destroyed()
    {
        if(this.requestSubscription)
            this.requestSubscription.unsubscribe();
    },
    methods:
    {
        errorHandler()
        {
            this.isLoading = false;
            this.items = [];
        },
        search: debounce(async function()
        {
            if(this.searchable.length > 0 && this.searchable.length < 2) return;
            this.isLoading = true;
            await this.getItems(false);
        }, 300),
        async getItems(isCancelable = true)
        {
            try
            {
                this.page = 0;
                this.items = await this.$store.dispatch(this.apiLocation, Object.assign({
                    top: this.innerConfig.itemsPerPage,
                    load: false,
                    skip: this.skip,
                    [this.searchParameter]: this.searchable ? this.searchable : null,
                    cancelable: isCancelable,
                    isThrowable: true,
                }, this.additionalSearchFields));

                this.isLoading = false;

                const allItems = this.filterItems(this.items);

                if(allItems.length === 0)
                    this.$emit("on-no-items");
                this.pagingLoadingState = LOADING_STATES.DEFAULT;
                this.findSelectedItem();
            }
            catch(error)
            {
                this.errorHandler(error);
            }
        },
        async findSelectedItem()
        {
            if(!this.selectedId) return;
            const item = this.comboItems.find(item => item.value === this.selectedId);

            if(item)
            {
                const selectedItem = CSItem({
                    value: this.selectedId,
                    label: item ? item.label : null,
                    ...item
                });
                this.selectedItem = selectedItem;
                this.iterations = 0;
            }
            else
            {

                {
                    if(!this.apiDetailsLocation) return;
                    if(this.iterations === 1) return;
                    const itemDetails = await this.$store.dispatch(this.apiDetailsLocation, {
                        id: this.selectedId,
                        isThrowable: true
                    });

                    this.items.push(itemDetails);
                    this.iterations = 1;
                    await this.findSelectedItem();
                }
                catch (error)
                {
                    console.error(error);
                }
            }

        },
        selectItem(item)
        {
            this.selectedItem = item;
            // check if it should be sent
            if(this.canSendDifferentValue)
                this.$emit('input', item.value);
            this.$emit('on-select-item', item);
            this.close();
        },
        async onScrollEnd()
        {
            if(this.isPagingLoading || this.isPagingLoadingBlocked || (this.searchable.length > 0 && this.searchable.length < 2)) return;
            try
            {
                this.pagingLoadingState = LOADING_STATES.LOADING;
                this.page++;
                const items = await this.$store.dispatch(this.apiLocation, Object.assign({
                    top: this.innerConfig.itemsPerPage,
                    load: false,
                    skip: this.skip,
                    [this.searchParameter]: this.searchable ? this.searchable : null,
                    isThrowable: true,
                }, this.additionalSearchFields));

                if(items.length === 0)
                {
                    this.pagingLoadingState = LOADING_STATES.BLOCKED;
                    return;
                }

                this.items = this.items.concat(items);

                const allItems = this.filterItems(this.items);

                if(allItems.length === 0)
                {
                    this.$emit("on-no-items");
                }

                this.pagingLoadingState = LOADING_STATES.DEFAULT;
            }
            catch(error)
            {
                console.error(error);
                this.errorHandler(error);
                this.pagingLoadingState = LOADING_STATES.DEFAULT;
            }
        },
        filterItems(items)
        {
            return this.innerConfig.itemsFilter ? this.innerConfig.itemsFilter(items) : items;
        },
        dispatch(action)
        {
            this.$emit("on-button-action", action);
        },
        toggleComboOpenState()
        {
            if(!this.innerConfig.isEditable) return;
            return this.openState = this.isOpen ? COMBO_STATES.CLOSED : COMBO_STATES.OPEN;
        },
        close()
        {
            this.openState = COMBO_STATES.CLOSED;
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div
      v-click-outside="close"
      :class="['combo-select', { 'combo-select__disabled': !isComboSelectEditable }]"
      @click="toggleComboOpenState"
    >
      <span class="combo-select__selecteditem">
        <span
          v-if="comboSelectItem === 'Select'"
          id="selected-item"
        >{{ comboSelectItem }}</span>
        <span
          v-else
          id="selected-item"
          v-tippy="{ placement : 'bottom', content: comboSelectItem, }"
        >{{ comboSelectItem }}</span>
      </span>
      <font-awesome-icon
        icon="caret-down"
        class="dropdown--arrow f-22"
      />

      <transition
        name="slidedown"
        appear
      >
        <div
          v-if="isOpen"
          class="sub-menu"
        >
          <section class="sub-search input input__typeahead field">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input
                v-model="searchable"
                v-focus
                type="text"
                :placeholder="innerConfig.searchLabel"
                @click.stop=""
                @input="search"
              >
              <div class="input-group-append">
                <font-awesome-icon
                  v-if="!isLoading"
                  icon="search"
                  class="typeahead-icon"
                />
                <font-awesome-icon
                  v-if="isLoading"
                  icon="spinner"
                  class="fa-spin relative f-25 cl-body"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
          <infinite-scroll
            v-if="!hasSubitemSlot"
            :button="button"
            :is-loading="isPagingLoading"
            @scroll-end="onScrollEnd"
          >
            <template #list>
              <h2
                v-for="(item, index) in comboItems"
                :key="`${item.label}-${index}`"
                v-tippy="{
                  placement : 'bottom',
                  content: item.label,
                }"
                :class="['sub-menu__item', {'selected': selectedItem.value === item.value}]"
                @click.stop="selectItem(item)"
              >
                {{ item.label }}
              </h2>
              <h2
                v-if="hasNoItems"
                class="sub-menu__item pointer-events-none"
              >
                No items
              </h2>
            </template>
          </infinite-scroll>

          <infinite-scroll
            v-if="hasSubitemSlot"
            :button="button"
            :is-loading="isPagingLoading"
            @scroll-end="onScrollEnd"
          >
            <template #list>
              <div
                v-for="(item, index) in comboItems"
                :key="`${item.label}-${index}`"
              >
                <slot
                  name="subitem"
                  :index="index"
                  :item="item"
                  :isSelected="selectedItem.value === item.value"
                  :close="close"
                  :action="selectItem"
                />
                <h2
                  v-if="hasNoItems"
                  class="sub-menu__item pointer-events-none"
                >
                  No items
                </h2>
              </div>
            </template>
          </infinite-scroll>
          <section
            v-if="button"
            class="sub-button"
          >
            <button
              class="btn btn--creation btn--creation--grey btn--creation--square w-100 h-100 br-r-0"
              @click="dispatch(button.action)"
            >
              <font-awesome-icon :icon="button.icon" />
              <span>{{ button.text }}</span>
            </button>
          </section>
          <!-- this should be shown only on infinite loading -->
        </div>
      </transition>
    </div>
    <span
      v-if="details"
      class="flex w-mc f-11 cl-6f-grey p-l-10 p-t-3"
    >({{ details }})</span>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I added the combo-select. I updated my noCitySelected method and I was able to remove the selected option but I can't clear the label from the input.

Answer (score 0):

You should show your UI component library name, because `combo-select` would have its own usage.

Maybe you can install [vue-devtools](https://devtools.vuejs.org/) to inspect data or other bugs in your development environment.